# Telegram Bot Conflict Error: Multiple Instances Running - Node.js

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api, render.com

I am using `node-telegram-bot-api` [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-telegram-bot-api) when I run the `app.js` file on my pc it does not give any error.

But when I use `render.com` [render](https://render.com/) to deploy my project it throws an error.

[Render error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWarU.png)

The app is running and it send messages but I also use `node-cron` to schedule messages and it does not work.

I tried many solutions like make a new bot, check if I am running it twice but there is no problem!

The whole code => [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/mszakii/quran-bot)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.